# What are the tricks to make lazy initialization thread safe and efficiency considering the costs of sychronized keyword?

Tags: java, functional-programming, thread-safety, lazy-initialization

After reading the lazy initialization of expensive resources in the book around Page 106-108 - functional programming in Java by Venkat Subramaniam, it is found hard to understand the tricks with this code snippet

my understandings:
variable `heavy` in class `Holder` is of type `Supplier<Heavy>`

vs

local class `HeavyFactory` inside the method createAndCacheHeavy is a sub class extends Supplier

It seems only run once to execute that lambda method and then alter the outer member variable of class Holder.heavy

I am confused about below code the heavy is then later assigned with new reference pointing to the sub class extends Supplier

please if anyone could share hints the tricks here to gain the advantages of author proposed to save performance penalty from synchronized keyword and also taking care of thread safety. It also mentioned virtual proxy pattern. Did I miss out any key info to understand it?

```
package fpij;

import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Holder {
//only run once here? before heavy get reassigned to HeavyFactory, the local class to that lambda method?
  private Supplier<Heavy> heavy = () -> createAndCacheHeavy();

  public Holder() {
    System.out.println("Holder created");
  }

  public Heavy getHeavy() {
//the 2nd time it will call always the HeavyFactory.heavyInstance?
    return heavy.get();
  }


  private synchronized Heavy createAndCacheHeavy() {
//create a local class inside method? Is the real trick/hack here I missed out so it will avoid 2nd time the synchronized penalty?
    class HeavyFactory implements Supplier<Heavy> {
      private final Heavy heavyInstance = new Heavy();

      public Heavy get() { return heavyInstance; }
    }

    if(!HeavyFactory.class.isInstance(heavy)) {
      heavy = new HeavyFactory();
    }

    return heavy.get();
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Holder holder = new Holder();
    System.out.println("deferring heavy creation...");
    System.out.println(holder.getHeavy());
    System.out.println(holder.getHeavy());
  }
}


package fpij;

public class Heavy {
  public Heavy() { System.out.println("Heavy created"); }

  public String toString() { return "quite heavy"; }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if I got the author intention is to run once only in that createAndCacheHeavy method and then the outer variable "heavy" has been assigned to HeavyFactory so the get method of HeavyFactory will not suffer from penalty although it seems still suffering in the scope of the outer synchronized method createAndCacheHeavy but actually no more suffering. Is anyone could elaborate more if my understandings is correct  or the tricks here?

Comment: Ah, yes. I missed the part where the `heavy` instance is replaced.

Comment: With that realization I think your understanding is correct. However, other threads may subsequently still invoke `createAndCacheHeavy()` since the `heavy` field is not volatile. This won't cause more than one instance to be created though, and within the same thread the reassignment of `heavy` will obviously be visible.

Comment: There’s an important point, the field `heavyInstance` has been declared `final`. Since other threads may bypass the `synchronized` method when observing the `HeavyFactory` reference in `heavy` on their first read already, the `final` field is crucial to observe a correctly initialized `Heavy` object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really concerned on the cost of synchronized, there a simple way to make it work correctly while keeping the initialization lazy.

It use the property that the classloader ensure synchronization when the class is loaded. It garentee that no other thread will be able to access the class until it is fully loaded. And the class load is actually lazy: it load the class only when the class is actually used from the first time.

If the only feature of class HeavyFactory is to provide the singleton instance, it will be loaded only when the getInstance is called and all will play nicely.

```
class HeavyFactory {

private static final Heavy heavyInstance = initInstance();

  public static Heavy getHeavyInstance() {
    return heavyInstance;
  }

  private static Heavy initInstance() {
      heavyInstance = new HeavyInstance();
      [...] // Other init stuff
      return heavyInstance;
  }
}
```

Edit: The init of complex objects and wiring of dependencies is so common that frameworks like JEE or Spring have implemented ways to do simplify it.

If you use spring for example, you would be able to just declare a given service as a singleton and then declare a dependency on it where you need it. The init would be done when the spring framework initialize in proper order:

```
// We instruct spring to create a shared instance of heavy
// with @Component annotation
// The instance would be created eagerly at the start of the app.
@Component
public class Heavy {
  public Heavy() { System.out.println("Heavy created"); }

  public String toString() { return "quite heavy"; }
}



// For the example another service using the Heavy shared instance
@Component
public class ClientDependingOnHeavy {

  // We ask spring to fill it automatically the shared instance for us.
  @Autowired
  private Heavy heavy; 


  public String foo() {
    //So we can use the instance like any object. 
    System.out.println(heavy.toString());
  }
}
```

Well spring or JEE are quite complex advanced frameworks. For a single case they would not be worth it at all. For a whole application it would make sense. You'd need quite some reading/tutorials to make the second example work if you don't already know them. But in the long run, it may be worth the effort.